# Get random message from json by js

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem with getting random messages from json in my js file.

```js
const values = Object.values(jsonData) 
/*const randomValue = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]*/ 
const randomValue = jsonData.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]; 
console.log(randomValue.quote);
```

He give me the first object. I want to give me a random one, not the first.

Comment: Please show the value of `jsonData`.

Comment: This is because you don't have passed arguments in math.random() function by default it will return a value between 0 to 1.

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal `Math.random` is a nullary function, which means it doesn't receive any arguments.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry! @YuriyYakym I made a mistake but by default it will return between 0 and 1

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal yes, but why is it a problem? There is a multiplication and flooring - usual way of getting a random integer in range

Comment: suppose if there values.length =1 then it might be a case

Comment: Welcome to SO. Debug the values of `values` and `jsonData`. Probably they have length `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close to a proper solution. If you did this `const values = jsonData.quotes` your code would work.

The problem is that you used `values.length` instead of `jsonData.quotes.length` in random index calculation.

```js
const quotes = jsonData.quotes;
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
const randomQuote = quotes[randomIndex];

console.log(randomQuote);
```

*PS. use more descriptive variable names, and it will be harder to introduce a bug. `values` is too ambiguous name.*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get a random element from your object's `quotes` array but you're only getting `Object.values` from `jsonData`. You need to get the values of `jsonData.quotes` instead.

```js
const jsonData = { quotes: [{ quote: 1 }, { quote: 2 }, { quote: 3 }] };

const values = Object.values(jsonData.quotes); 

const randomValue = jsonData.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]; 

console.log(randomValue.quote);
```

Comment: Thank you, But i have quote and author like that. "quotes": [

{
       "quote":"Life isn’t about getting and having, it’s about giving and being.","author":"Kevin Kruse"},

Comment: This was an example. My data is basically the same as yours. I'm just returning numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need a main array inside your JSON and save your data inside of it, like:

```
var jsonContent = {
        "main": [
            {
                "id": "111",
                "title": "post title 111",
                "desc": "This is a test desc 111"
            },
            {
                "id": "222",
                "title": "post title 222",
                "desc": "This is a test desc 222"
            },
            {
                "id": "333",
                "title": "post title 333",
                "desc": "This is a test desc 333"
            }
        ]
    }

    var random = jsonContent.featured[Math.floor(Math.random() * jsonContent.main.length)];
    console.log(random)
```

Replace your JSON objects with:

```
{
    "id": "333",
    "title": "post title 333",
    "desc": "This is a test desc 333"
}
```

Inside of `"main"`

*I hope it help you.*

Comment: It is not the solution but it helps me very much. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Math.random() * jsonData.length`.
The solution is very simple i don't multiple with all values

```js
Math.random() * jsonData.quotes.length
```